# pipe and fork: Sharing one file descriptor across multiple children

Tags: c, posix

I have a parent process that forks multiple times. I pipe once at the start of the program and then fork multiple times. Can I use the same file descriptor across all children to write to the parent? Or do I have to pipe for each new child and have a separate file descriptor for each?

As of right now, the first child can write to the write end of the pipe no problem but the second child gets a bad file descriptor error when it tries to write.

The code to write is the same across all children.

Comment: While as you found out, you can perfectly share the fd of a pipe across fork'ed process -- then depending on how you write the data the data may be mingled if multiple processes writes to the same pipe -- which may  or may not cause you a problem depending on the purpose of the communication.

Comment: Thanks. The program is a mock scheduler for a school project to show us about signals basically. Only one process is gonna be running at a time therefore no race conditions will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was being an idiot. I forked once when I entered the program, closed the write end of the pipe in the parent and then forked again providing any subsequent child with a closed writing end.

```
pipe(fd);
pid = fork();

if (!pid) { /* Insert first child code */ }
else {

    close(fd[1]);    /* Close write end of pipe */

    pid = fork();    /* Fork again. */
    /* ... */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but the second child gets a bad file descriptor error when it tries to write.

of course, because for each new process you need to open new files to handle was valid. 
just open the pipe for each new process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <fcntl.h> 
char str1[] = "string from 1-st proc";
char str2[] = "string from 2-st proc";
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[100];
    mkfifo("/tmp/my_fifo", 0777);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        //it is child
        int pipe_chld = open("/tmp/my_fifo", O_WRONLY);
        write(pipe_chld, str1, sizeof(str1));
        if (fork() == 0) {
            //it is child
            int pipe_chld = open("/tmp/my_fifo", O_WRONLY);
            write(pipe_chld, str2, sizeof(str2));
            exit(0);
        } else {
            exit(0);
        }
    } else {
        //it is parent
        int fd_fifo = open("/tmp/my_fifo", O_RDONLY);
        read(fd_fifo, buf, 100);
        read(fd_fifo, buf + sizeof(str1), 100);
        printf("%s, %s\n", buf, buf + sizeof(str1));
        exit(0);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Actually I just solved this and I don't need a new pipe. Once I had forked once, I closed the write end of the pipe on the parent therefore any further fork provided a closed end to the children.

Comment: you don't need new pipe, you need re-open old pipe for each new process

Comment: You can't reopen a closed pipe. Once it's closed, it's closed. In fact how would you do that? The open system call doesn't take a file descriptor as a parameter.

Comment: that's what I had in mind, see above, I added the my answer

Comment: I was specifically referring to the pipe command as stated in the title but I can see how this could work. Thanks for replying.